# $f$ is $\mu$-integrable $\Leftrightarrow \, \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}2^n\mu(\{x\in X\mid2^n<f(x)\leq 2^{n+1}\})$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measurable space and $f:X \rightarrow[0,\infty[$ a measurable function

$f$ is $\mu$-integrable iif...
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}2^n\mu(\{x\in X\mid2^n<f(x)\leq 2^{n+1}\})$$

is convergent

---

I thought about it this way...

$f$ is $\mu$-integrable and $f \geq 0$ $\Rightarrow \,\int_X f \,d\mu < \infty$

Because $f$ is measurable $\Rightarrow f = \sum_{i=1} \alpha_i \mathbf{1}_{A_i}$  where $A_i \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\mathbf{1}$ is the indicator function.

We also know that the Integral of $f$ is therefore... $\int f\, d\mu = \sum_{i=1} \alpha_i \mu(A_i) < \infty$

Now it gets a bit tricky. I'm assuming $Z:=\{x\in X\mid2^n<f(x)\leq 2^{n+1}\} \in \mathcal{A}$, otherwise the notation wouldn't make much sense.

Then I think I'm practically done. Since $2^n$ is a lower bound for the function-values, we can assume, that $\alpha_i \geq 2^n$ for that set. Therefore...

$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}2^n\mu(\{x\in X\mid2^n<f(x)\leq 2^{n+1}\})\leq \sum_{i=1} \alpha_i \mu(A_n)<\infty$$

should be true, because $Z$ is also in the RHS of the inequality.

I'm assuming my thinking is incorrect, but that's the best I can come up with right now.

Hoping for any helpful tips how to solve that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dou you mean: $f$ is $\mu$-integrable iff  $\sum \ldots$ **is finite**?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3917096/42969

Comment: @Martin R *convergent, sorry!

Comment: Helpful link. Thanks =)